# Turning column values to row elements with awk

Tags: awk, unique

I have a data like this.

```
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    2
e    2
f    2
```

I wanna take rows something like ;

```
a,b,c    1
d,e,f    2
```

Can I achieve this with awk command?

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Sorry. This is my first question here and I am also so new with these kind of things. But I corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way with the caveats that 1) the input file must fit in memory and 2) the output order is unspecified:

```
$ awk '$2 in a { a[$2] = a[$2] "," $1; next }
       { a[$2] = $1 }
       END { for (i in a) print a[i], i }' file
d,e,f 2
a,b,c 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    { printf "%s%s", ($2==p ? "," : end), $1; p=$2; end="\t" p ORS }
    END { printf "%s", end }
' file
a,b,c   1
d,e,f   2
```